# SharePoint:SaveButton save and then close window with Javascript

Tags: 2010, javascript

I'd like to have the standard SharePoint save button 
    **SharePoint:SaveButton**
To use JavaScript to close the open window (this is not a modal, but the actual window or tab) when it is finished. Is this possible? I'd prefer not to use jQuery for something so simple if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced the SharePoint save button with the following HTML/JavaScript. It even has an alert.

```
<input name="Submit1" type="submit" value="Save Changes" id="Submit1" style="width:140px" onclick="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit')}; window.alert('Item updated.') ; window.close();"  />
```

This button saves the SharePoint item, sends an alert, then closes the window after the alert is acknowledged.

Here is a simple Cancel button which does not redirect, but will close the window instead.

```
<input name="Button1" type="button" value="Cancel" style="width:140px"  onclick="javascript: window.close();"/>
```

Comment: I tried this solution but it is not working for me.. even alert is not getting fired... can you please provide me any alternate solution if you have one ..

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used. Bear in mind this logic works when the page it is on has been opened up in a new tab. Also note I am not doing any javascript alert for telling the user (because it's implied in button text value).

Enclosed this on the page that is opened in a new window/tab:

```
HtmlGenericControl btnClose = new HtmlGenericControl("input");
btnClose.Attributes["type"] = "button";
btnClose.Attributes["style"] = "text-align:center; font-size:13px; font-color:#000; font-weight:bold";
btnClose.Attributes["onclick"] = "window.open('', '_self', ''); window.close();";
btnClose.Attributes["value"] = "Click here to close this window or tab.";
            this.Controls.Add(btnClose);
```

Added the event for sharepoint since javascript is so finicky in SharePoint:

```
protected void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string script = "<script type='javascript'>window.open('','_parent',''); window.close();</script>";
   Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "Register", script);
}
```

The window.open that is used is a workaround to ensure most browsers will accept.